# Elastic Search group by a text field throws error Fielddata is disabled on text fields by default

Tags: elasticsearch, indexing, kibana

I am new to elastic search, as of now i have a requirement cause of which i need to group by a text field.

Now the most common answer to this question is to enable field data on an existing text field using the PUT mapping API.

Is there a simpler way to account for this situation without updating a template or index.

sample query:

```
GET ****/message/_search
        {
          "_source": ["identifier"],
          "size": 0,
          "aggs": {
            "group_by_coll_conv": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "identifier"
              },
              "aggs": {
                "count" : {
                  "value_count" : 
                    { 
                      "field" : "something" 
                    } 
                }
              }
            }
          }
```

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks

Comment: if you need more insight, please read this page. You must know why this problem happened.  https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/fielddata.html

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The other easier way you are asking for:

You can just append **.keyword** to the field name you want to search text from. 
**For eg**: field name is identifier, so just use it as **identifier.keyword**

This will help you for sure.

Comment: Thank you Ranvijay Jamwal, this solved my problem :)

Comment: Welcome @DeepSinghBaweja

Comment: hey it is not working for me can you share actual query you have used ? i am not specifying source while making this call ? i am getting no data in the bucket, though appending keyword resolved the error but yet there is no response